# Where to find an example of the Actions?

Tags: libgdx

I do not work Actions.moveTo.

```
actor.addAction(Actions.moveTo(500, 500, 1));
```

Please show me a working example.

Thank you.

`ADD CODE`:

```
stage.addActor(actor);
actor.addAction(Actions.moveTo(500, 500, 1));
```

...

```
@Override
public void render () {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
    stage.draw();
}
```

Comment: you need to call `act` on the actor so it precesses the action

Comment: @realUser404, I am call `stage.act`. Updated question.

Comment: @Tyyppi_77, There I asked what went wrong. No answer.
Here I ask a working example.

Comment: Not receiving an answer doesn't make it acceptable to post duplicated questions, and this definitely feels like one to me.

Comment: You should put a bounty on your other question to raise awareness and get more answers instead of asking again. You should also make sure your question is complete and correct when you hit the 'Post question' button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you call `act` with the `delta time` on your `Stage` then any `Action`s that you have on the `Actor`s in that `Stage` will be affected.

Looking at your `render` method this looks correct, so I can only assume the problem is when you set up the `Actor` and its corresponding `Action`.

A working example could look something like this:

```
package com.bornander.lpcsandbox;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.actions.Actions;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Image;

public class LpcGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter  {
    SpriteBatch batch;
    Texture img;
    Stage stage;

    @Override
    public void create () {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        img = new Texture("badlogic.jpg");
        stage = new Stage();
        Image image = new Image(img);
        image.addAction(Actions.moveTo(100,100, 5));
        stage.addActor(image);
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
        stage.draw();
    }
}
```